# What's the best method to design an adjustable power supply with 0-240V output?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I need to design a power supply for a DC shunt motor that has 240v,1.75A armature current, and 0.2A excitation current.

I was wondering which is the easiest/reliable method to design the power supply, to be adjustable and short circuit proof.

P.S. The mains power is 240V.

Comment: easiest? cheap? small? light? Define "best"...

Comment: Simplest to be made with parts that are most common, size or weight don't matter.

Comment: For adjustable SMPS I generally go for buck-derived topologies, especially the forward converter. The power level is quite suitable for a forward converter but going down to zero volts is going to be one of your biggest problems.

Comment: Do you want an adjustable PS, or adjustable mechanical power/torque/speed? What about *overload proof*, *startup current*? (Are you positive it's not a [universal motor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_motor)?)

Comment: (I don't think tag [DC-DC converter](/tags/dc-dc-converter/info) applies.)

Answer (score 1):

Current-mode buck is a strong go-to.

Current mode operation means intrinsically limited inductor current, and thus load current to a certain extent.  Which further protects the switch, eliminating one whole failure mode of the converter (overcurrent).

Voltage or RPM is controlled with an outer loop (error amp), which splits the complex pole pair of the output LC filter, allowing faster dynamics -- probably not a concern for motor control (if applicable at all, say if using direct drive), but is important for power supplies.

An outer current loop can also be used to better regulate current (input or output), or torque.

For a separate-field DC motor, simply make two channels of suitable rating, and run the field per whatever your control scheme is.

The field winding has considerable inductance by itself, so is a potentially strong candidate for direct drive (unfiltered), and something even simpler, like hysteretic current control might be used, versus peak or average current mode.

To sense current, consider a high-side current sensor / differential amplifier, like INA1xx (various suitable parts), AD8210, ZXCT1107 (with suitable improvements if use above nominal voltage rating is required), etc., and a low-side switch (and driver and controller).  You'll also need an H-bridge if reversal is required; direction can simply be selected by a polarity signal, and the same control scheme used on the active-switching side.